# How move info under image when resize screen? using only css

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image that when fullscreen shows info on the right, but when you resize the screen smaller that info moves below the image. how would i do this?

```
<div class="container">

<h1>LandScape</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="item">
        <img src="#">
        <h3>Ferrari LaFerrari<span>car info</span></h3>
        <ul class="info">
            <li><h4><i class="icon icon camera">Canon Powershot S95</h4></li>
            <li>22.5 MM</li>
            <li>f/5.6</li>
            <li>1/1000</li>
            <li>80</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the CSS you are using already. And even better, make a JSfilddle or similar to show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Without more concrete data, I can only give you the general gist of
1)

```
display:inline-block
```

-> image and info in a row
and 2)
the media queries like such:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
...
}
```

see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/wofseL6z/